# Entity Framework code first, one table inheritance : how to put foreign key relationship on discrimator column?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a one table inheritance in EF Code first, the discriminator column is an integer, which is foreign key.. but when you define a column as a discriminator, you have to remove it as property on the base class. And this property is needed to be able to define a foreign key relationship on this column... is there another way to do it?

```
A                                        B
TypeId (=discriminator column)     ==>   Id
```

Answer (score 0):

No. You can have either discriminator or foreign key / relationship defined by the column. It cannot be used for both in the same time.

Comment: That is strange... with Linq 2 SQL this was perfectly possible